# Не считывает строку

Tags: java

помогите понять почему не считывает строку? Мало того, я даже не успею ее задавать. Как только комментирую ввод int/double, то действие со строкой выполняется безошибочно.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Print {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        double d;
        String str;

       a=scanner.nextInt();
       d=scanner.nextDouble();
       str=scanner.nextLine();


       System.out.println("String: "+str);
       System.out.println("Double: "+d);
       System.out.println("Int: "+a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Поставьте str=scanner.nextLine(); первым

Comment: В задаче необходимо ввести строку последней и прочесть ее первой :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В задаче необходимо ввести строку последней и прочесть ее первой :(

Вряд ли это у Вас получится. Вы, нaверное, хотели сказать "вывести строку первой".

---

```
   a = scanner.nextInt();
   scanner.nextLine();
   d = scanner.nextDouble();
   scanner.nextLine();
   str = scanner.nextLine();
```